# WPF - change control's text font size according to used languge

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization

I have a C# desktop application, GUI is in WPF.
I have all kind of controls, such as: buttons, radio buttons that have text in them, in a specified font size. All looks great in English.
But, when I change the language of my app to be something else (I have localization on my app), for example: French, German, Italian... The text is cut, because it's too long.
I would like to change the **font size of the control to be automatically fitted to the text length in the specific current language**. Not just to change the font to be small enough by default for all languages.
Is there a way to do that **in WPF**?
Thanks!!!

Comment: How about wrapping the text? something like:<Button>
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Some text</TextBlock>
</Button>

Comment: @GregOks, my button doesn't have textBlock, but a Content attribute. I don't think I can wrap it.

Comment: <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="175"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Style="{StaticResource BottomNavigation_ButtonStyle}"
                        Content="{l:Translation NewPatient}"
                        Tag="/Resources/Icons/2015/New-patient.png"
                        Command="{Binding EnterNewPatientCommand}"
                        Visibility="{Binding IsNewSessionMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on setting the `Width` of the Button, one option is to simply wrap the `Button` in a `ViewBox`:

```
<Viewbox Width = "100" >
    <Button  Content="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">
    </Button>
</Viewbox>
```

However, you might want to consider retemplating and wrapping the `ContentPresenter` in a `ViewBox`:

```
<Button Width = "100" Content="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Viewbox x:Name="ViewBoxInternal">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Viewbox>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

you can use [its Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.110).aspx) to add other animations/effects.

Comment: Hi @Ron, thanks for feedback. However, wrapping in 'Viewbox' didn't solve my problem - text is still cut and not resized. As for the second solution, I tried to add this piece of code to my button xml description, didn't work either - it just overrieded my style description.

Comment: Would you please update the question and show your code?

Comment: @NettaD There was a mistake, which I corrected. You should set the Width of the ``ViewBox`` instead of the ``Button`` in the first example.